# Bound variable not displaying new value in UI

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have this code in my page:

```cs
@if (players == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <p>Number of Players: @players.Count</p>
    <p>Number of Teams: @teamsCount</p>
    <p>Excess Players: @excessPlayers</p>
}
@code {
    private List<PlayerModel> players;
    private int teamsCount { get; set; }
    private int excessPlayers { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        players = await _db.GetPlayers();

        int teamsCount = players.Count / 5;
        int excessPlayers = players.Count % 5;
    }
```

The loading html is displayed correctly for a time and then `players.Count` is correctly updating and showing 41, but `teamsCount` and `excessPlayers` always display 0.

I have tried calling `StateHasChanged()` at the end of `OnInitializedAsync()`.

I have also tried setting `teamsCount` and `excessPlayers` in a separate method and calling `StateHasChanged()` but neither of those worked. Both `teamsCount` and `excessPlayers` still remain displayed as 0, although I can see that in the code they are 8 and 1 respectively, which is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how about `<p>Number of Teams: @(players.Count / 5)</p>`?

Comment: That does work and it will show 8 as expected. However I'd like to understand why setting the variable in code is not being reflected in the UI as I would expect (and indeed, seems to work in other places).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new local variables for `teamsCount` and `excessPlayers` in your `OnInitializedAsync` method:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    players = await _db.GetPlayers();

    int teamsCount = players.Count / 5;
    int excessPlayers = players.Count % 5;
}
```

You should be setting the values of your properties instead:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    players = await _db.GetPlayers();

    teamsCount = players.Count / 5;
    excessPlayers = players.Count % 5;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. I am an idiot! I can't believe I didn't spot that. Thanks.